# String Following REGEX

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex

```
$pattern = '/\b\d{4}-\d{4}\b/';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
```

I need to get the 5 words after that regex. Any ideas how I would accomplish this?

For example " Power Slot Slotted Rotors - 1997-1998 Oldsmobile Regency - Brakes & Brake Pads - Brake Rotors."

I need to return "1997-1998 Oldsmobile Regency - Brakes &";

Any ideas?

**// Update from the bottom comments.**

There might be multiple matches in one string. For instance

"For example:"2000-2009 Ford Explorer, 2000-2010 Ford Ranger. 1674SJT JBA Cat4ward Headers Features"

I'm still trying to get the 1st 5 "non white spaces" after the number sequence xxxx-xxxx.

Comment: That *isn't* "the 5 words after"... that is "the **match and** 5 words after"

Comment: Plus if we're being pedantic (and pedantry seems to be something of a hobby around here) `-` and `&` are not technically *words*...

Comment: @DaveRandom Being pedantic you have to say that '-' and '&' _are_ indeed words from a technical perspective :-)

Comment: @Dave, unfortunately, when it comes to computing, pedantry is somewhat necessary.  If you are given a specification that says "the 5 words after" and then find out that what you have provided was not what they were after it would be rather annoying (but unfortunately common!!)

Comment: @arkascha `-` certainly isn't, it represents an inflection if translated to spoken form. And when you consider `\w` (perl "words") neither of them are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your edits, try this:

```
/\b\d{4}-\d{4}(?:\s(?!\d{4}-\d{4})\S+){1,5}\b/
```

[See it working](http://viper-7.com/oFFmrJ)

With thanks to @Ariel for the regex this is based on, which was correct until additional requirements were specified through edits. If you like this, go upvote that answer as well ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
/\b\d{4}-\d{4}( [^ ]*){5}\b/
```

Get a space followed by anything except a space (i.e. a word). And do it 5 times.

Comment: I would suggest `\s` rather than `<space>` - or maybe even `\b`

Comment: @DaveRandom That includes newlines, and I don't know if he wants that.

Comment: This seems to work unless it followed by a similar match. For example:"2000-2009 Ford Explorer, 2000-2010 Ford Ranger. 1674SJT JBA Cat4ward Headers Features" Results in:Array
(
    [0] => 2000-2009 Ford Explorer, 2000-
    [1] => 2000-
)

Comment: Fair point. I have to say, I have never understood why a newline is a horizontal whitespace (`\h`) and not a vertical whitespace (`\v`) character. +1 by the way.

Comment: @JasonSmall Well, you have moved the goal posts a little there - you didn't say there could be multiple sequential matches and that makes it more interesting. Are they always comma separated? Can a comma ever appear in the words you want to extract?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I didn't think multiple occurrences would be a problem. The only way to tell if there is a second match would be a repeat of the number sequence xxxx-xxxx There might not always be a comma.

Comment: @DaveRandom Awesome that worked great. Do you want to submit it as the answer and  I'll mark it as accepted?